# How many sequences of length 6 are formed from the $26$ letters without repetition where the first or last letter (possibly both) must not be vowels?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many sequences of length $6$ are formed from the $26$ letters without repetition where the first or last letter (possibly both) must not be vowels?

I am so lost and confused, but here's my approach:

- Total number of sequences should be: $$26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times 22 \times 21$$
- First letter not a vowel: $$21 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times22 \times 21$$
- Last letter not a vowel:

- All $5$ vowels used previously: $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 21$$
- $4$ vowels are used previously: $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 21 \times 20$$
- $3$ vowels are used previously: $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 21 \times 20 \times 19$$
- $2$ vowels are used previously: $$5 \times 4 \times 21 \times 20 \times 19 \times 18$$
- $1$ vowel is used previously: $$5 \times 21 \times 20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17$$

I don't know if this is the right approach and if it is, I don't know where to go from here. Could you please help me understand the methodology of solving these types of problems?

The solution is given to be: $$2\times21\times5\times{24P4} + 21\times20\times{24P4}$$ or else $$26P6 - 5\times4\times{24P4}$$

Comment: Your approach suffers from the complication that in the "last letter not a vowel" case you are trying to choose the first five letters before choosing the last letter.  There's no reason you can't choose the last letter of the word before choosing the first five letters, which will greatly simplify things.

Comment: Question: instead of "last letter not a vowel", did you mean "last letter not a vowel but first letter is a vowel"?  I think you need the extra stipulation to avoid overlap with the "first letter not a vowel" case; the extra stipulation is also consistent with your not having included "0 vowels are used previously" among your cases.  If that's what you meant, then your analysis was close to being complete.  You omitted one thing: in the "4 vowels used previously" case, you...

Comment: ...have the middle four letters in VVVC (V=vowel, C=consonant) order, but there are, in fact, four possible orders: VVVC, VVCV, VCVV, CVVV.  In general, if the middle four letters include $r$ consonants and $4-r$ vowels, there are $\binom{4}{r}$ orders.  If you include these binomial coefficient factors, your answer will agree with the stated solutions.

Comment: @WillOrrick I didn't mean that. I was only focusing on the last letter not being a vowel but for some reason I kept thinking that the other letters needed to be picked first and they can be a vowel. But I should have included where none of them were vowels.

Comment: If you do that, then you will have double counted the case "neither first nor last letter a vowel".  This would then have to be subtracted away to get the correct count.  Better not to include it in the first place.  Of course it's even better to go with one of the methods that involves fewer cases.

Comment: @WillOrrick Yeah, I see what you're saying. I generally get confused over what questions to ask since my professor keeps saying that is the key to solving these types of question. Thank you for your all your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the given solution is a result of:

$1$)  Counting the number of arrangements with exactly one vowel - either at the beginning or the end:

- Choose whether the vowel goes at the beginning or end:  $2$ ways.
- Choose a non-vowel to fill the non-vowel spot at the beginning or end: $21$ ways.
- Choose a vowel to fill the vowel spot at the beginning or end:  $5$ ways.
- Choose the sequence of letters to fill the middle $24P4$ ways.

$2$)  Counting the number of arrangements with no vowels:

- Choose a non-vowel for the first spot:  $21$ ways.
- Choose a non-vowel for the last spot:  $20$ ways.
- Choose the sequence of letters to fill the middle $24P4$ ways.

So the total number of acceptable arrangements is  $$2\times 21 \times 5\times 24P4 + 21\times 20\times 24P4 $$

The "or else" part of the given solution is a result of:

1. Counting the number of possible sequences of length $6$ from the $26$ letters without repetition:  $26P6$  (this is the same as your "total number of sequences")
2. Subtracting the sequences where both the first and last letters are vowels:

   a)  Choose the two vowels.  This can be done in $5\times4$ ways.

   b)  Choose the remaining letters.  This can be done in $24P4$ ways.

   c)  The total number of these arrangements is  $5\times4\times 24P4$

So the total number of acceptable arrangements is  $26P6 - 5\times 4\times 24P4 $.

I'm out of time for the moment, but if possible, I'll come back and comment about how these compare with your calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems it's easier to look for opposite of the requirement and subtract it from all possible outcomes so that the remaining outcomes are the ones with the constraints. Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm interpreting the clause "where the first or last letter (possibly both) must not be vowels" as meaning that vowels are forbidden at the slots number 1 and 6. It seems that the intended meaning was: "the set of words whose first and last letters are not both vowels".

You have $26-5=21$ choices for the first letter and $20$ choices for the last letter. The four letters in between can be taken from the $26-2=24$ letters not used so far. This can be done in $24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21$ ways. The total number $N$ of admissible words is therefore given by
$$N=21\cdot20\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21=107110080\ .$$

Comment: The problem is asking for the union of the set of sequences such that the first letter is not a vowel with the set of sequences such that the last letter is not a vowel.  This is consistent with the two stated solutions (numerical value 160665120) and with the phrase "possibly both", which suggests that it is not necessary that both letters not be vowels.